# Write a function looping(my_func, interval, limit)

Tags: python

Question:

Write a function looping(my_func, interval, limit) which takes three input parameters and returns the pyplot object (i.e., plt).
my_func is a function passed in as an input (e.g., math.sin).
interval is the x-value interval starting from 0 (e.g., if interval = 1, then x-values are 0, 1, 2, 3, and if interval = 0.1, then x-values are 0, 0.1, 0.2 etc.).
limit is the x-value limit (up to, but not including).

The graph generated should use red colour with points represented using the point marker.

Using the example case values, it will look something like this. (And there is an image of the correct output)

Test code:

```
my_func = math.sin
interval = 0.05
limit = 4 * math.pi
plt1 = looping(my_func, interval, limit)
save_plt(plt1, "output.png")
plt2 = ans(my_func, interval, limit)
save_plt(plt2, "ans.png")
val = main("output.png", "ans.png")
if val <= 0.0001:
    print("Pass!")
else:
    print("Your graph is different to the expected output, difference: {:.4f}".format(val))
```

Result:

Pass!

My code: (I've tried a few variations, but none seem to work)

```
def looping(my_func, interval, limit):   
    x = np.arange(0, limit, interval)   
    y = []   
    for i in x:     
        y.append(my_func(i))   
    return plt.plot(x, np.array(y), 'r.')
```

Common errors I get:

```
***Run error***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__tester__.python3", line 71, in <module>
    save_plt(plt1, "output.png")
  File "__tester__.python3", line 31, in save_plt
    plt.savefig(fname)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'savefig'

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

The problem starts in your looping function:

```py
def looping(my_func, interval, limit):   
    x = np.arange(0, limit, interval)   
    y = []   
    for i in x:     
        y.append(my_func(i))   
    return plt.plot(x, np.array(y), 'r.')
```

Why? The looping function is returning the output of `plt.plot(...)` which is a `Line2D` object. I imagine that you use the output of this function in the `save_plt` function, but this doesn't work. Your looping function should return a plt.Figure object, hence you could modify your looping function to:

```py
def looping(my_func, interval, limit):   
    x = np.arange(0, limit, interval)   
    y = []   
    for i in x:     
        y.append(my_func(i))   
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, np.array(y), 'r.')
    return fig
```

I would advise you to use a debugger or run your code in a Jupyter notebook to check each variable type

Comment: hmmm, this is interesting: it came up with error code 
plt.close()
    ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'close'